# "attempt to create a temporary id buffer which is too large or with a negative count" NSGenericException on NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, exception, crash, nsarray

I've got the following lines of code (`a1` & `a2` are of type NS{Mutable,}Array):

```
NSIndexSet *is = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(a1.count, items.count-a1.count)];
[a2 addObjectsFromArray:[items objectsAtIndexes:is]];
```

According to Crittercism the second line crashes with a `NSGenericException` and message:

```
*** attempt to create a temporary id buffer which is too large or with a negative count (18446744073709551556) -- possibly data is corrupt
```

The bottom of the stack trace looks like this:

```
0   CoreFoundation 0x000000018595e084 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000195f940e4 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation 0x000000018586830c -[NSArray objectsAtIndexes:] + 1124
3   .... line of code for `[a2 addObjectsFromArray:[items objectsAtIndexes:is]]` ...
```

What could be causing this crash?

If I try to create an IndexSet with a location or length of `(NSUInteger)-60` (which could be the number in the exception), the `-initWithIndexesInRange:` already fails (with a different exception). Other "improper" ranges I've tried are caught as well.

If I try to just feed `-objectsAtIndexes:` an invalid pointer (e.g. -60 again), the app crashes with  a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash., not the exception I'm seeing.

Trying to find this error using Google only shows 1 hit - http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFInternal.h (line 564) ... but newer versions of CoreFramework don't contain that message any more (maybe it was just moved somewhere else).

Comment: So what is `a.count` then?

Comment: That should have been `a1` ... fixed now. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: It's hard to see the logic without more info, however you are using a size from `a1` but applying it to `a2`.

Comment: Mostly I'm interested in how to cause the `-objectsAtIndexes:` to crash in the way of the crash report ... I can make it crash, but not with that specific exception. I don't think the logic behind how the location & length parameters are calculated is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing a small program to iterate over possible location + length combinations it turns out that this crash happens any time that `length = 1 - location`.

For example:

```
NSRange     range = NSMakeRange(50, (NSUInteger)-49);
NSIndexSet *is    = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:range];
NSLog(@"indexSet: %@", is);
(void)[@[@1,@2,@3] objectsAtIndexes:is];
```

Outputs:

```
crash[19549:507] indexSet: <NSIndexSet: 0x7fe698402de0>[number of indexes: 18446744073709551567 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (50-0)]
crash[19549:507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** attempt to create a temporary id buffer which is too large or with a negative count (18446744073709551567) -- possibly data is corrupt'
*** First throw call stack:
    [...]
```